# Pregmatch using word boundary regex not working as expected

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using preg_match to find exact words and phrases and replace them with AHREF links. I am using word boundary regex but it is not working correctly. It is matching within words.

Example:
'rings' is being matched to 'ear*rings*'. I don't want that. I just want 'rings'

Is my preg_match regex wrong?

```
$keyword="rings";

$text="women's earrings, clothing rings, earrings, rings";

if (preg_match("/\b$keyword\b/i",$text))
```

*Italics* are meant to be underlined below

output = `"women's ear*rings*, clothing *rings*, ear*rings*, *rings*"`

expected = `"women's earrings, clothing *rings*, earrings, *rings*"`

*update*
I think the problem is in the replace function:

```
function str_replace_first($from, $to, $subject)
    {    $from = '/'.preg_quote($from, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject,2); 
    }

if (preg_match_all("/\b$keyword\b/i",$text,$matches)>0) 
    {
                print_r($matches)."<p> ";   

            $ahref="<a href='$anchor_url'>$keyword</a>";
            $text=str_replace_first($keyword, $ahref, $text);
           } ELSE {

                echo "<p>no Match<br>";
            }
echo $text;
```

Comment: Isn't your question more about replacing than just matching? Are you sure it's not the code thereafter (you haven't shown) which might need attention?

Comment: yes updated the code. i think the prob is in the replace function

Comment: Try `return preg_replace($from, $to, $subject, 1);` (you have `2` - you replace two matches).

Comment: Also, `preg_match_all("/\b$keyword\b/i",$text,$matches)` --> `preg_match_all("/\b".preg_quote($keyword, '/') . "\b/i",$text,$matches)`

Comment: You shouldn't do it in two steps. Use `preg_replace()` right away. Or `preg_replace_callback()` with a function - if you really need debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` directly, without collecting the matches since you are not really going to use them (you only need to wrap them up with some other texts):

```
$keyword="rings";
$anchor_url = "http_//www.t.tt";
$url = "<a href='$anchor_url'>\$0</a>";
$text="women's earrings, clothing rings, earrings, rings";
$newtxt = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($keyword, '/') . '\b/i', $url, $text);
if ($newtxt != $text) {
    echo $newtxt;
} else { echo "No matches!"; }
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/JsvUO7).

Note that you need `\b` word boundaries to match a whole word. You also need to `preg_quote` the keyword and escape the regex delimiter, too. Then, since you are using a case insensitive regex, you cannot use `$keyword` hardcoded in the replacement, you need to use `$0` backreference to the whole match. If you need to check if there was no match, just compare a new string with the original string.